# LISTAGG in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I am trying to use LISTAGG() to fetch more than two columns.

```
SELECT deptname, deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees 
FROM emp 
GROUP BY deptno;
```

But it is throwing this error:

```
: FROM keyword not found where expected
 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 12
```

Can please somebody explain why it is?

Comment: query is like this  SELECT deptname, deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees  FROM   emp  GROUP  BY  deptno;

Comment: GROUP BY deptno,deptname

Comment: Sounds as if your Oracle version is too old. LISTAGG was introduced with release 2 of version 11g; it's not available in the first release of 11g.

Answer (score 3):

The **LISTAGG** analytic function was introduced in **Oracle 11g Release 2**. So, if you are on older version, you won't be able to use it.

The error seems strange. You should actually get `ORA-00904: "DEPTNAME": invalid identifier` as the standard `EMP` table in `SCOTT` schema doesn't have DEPTNAME column. Also, you should get `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` as you did not mention the **SELECT**ed columns in the **GROUP BY** expression.

Using the standard **EMP** table in **SCOTT** schema:

```
SQL> SELECT deptno,
  2    job,
  3    LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (
  4  ORDER BY ename) AS employees
  5  FROM emp
  6  GROUP BY deptno,
  7    job;

    DEPTNO JOB       EMPLOYEES
---------- --------- ------------------------
        10 CLERK     MILLER
        10 MANAGER   CLARK
        10 PRESIDENT KING
        20 CLERK     ADAMS,SMITH
        20 ANALYST   FORD,SCOTT
        20 MANAGER   JONES
        30 CLERK     JAMES
        30 MANAGER   BLAKE
        30 SALESMAN  ALLEN,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT deptname, deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ename) AS employees 
FROM emp 
GROUP BY deptno,deptname;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle 11g:**

```
SELECT deptname, deptno, LISTAGG(ename, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY deptno,job) AS employees 
FROM emp 
GROUP BY deptno,job;
```

**Oracle 10g:**

```
SELECT deptname, deptno, WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(ename) AS employees 
FROM emp 
GROUP BY deptno,job;
```